# square iOS POS app add untaxed fee

Tags: square-connect

Can I add an untaxed delivery fee?  I tried using Modifiers, but it's taxable and messing with my price point and I want it for the whole order, not multiplied by each item ordered.  Is there a solution to this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create an item called "Delivery Fee" and set a price to it, but turn off the taxes for it in the dashboard. It will show up in the receipt just like any other item, but it's self explanatory as to what it is, and it will not be taxed.